# Image src in amazon site stripe

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, affiliate

I want to use images from Amazon in my WooCommerce affiliate product links. Apparently this is OK if you use the Amazon site sripe.

An example of the HTML from the stripe is below:

```
<a href="https://www.amazon.co.uk/Learn-Python-Hard-Way-Introduction/dp/0134692888/ref=as_li_ss_il?keywords=python&qid=1559649803&s=books&sr=1-38&linkCode=li2&tag=compucademy-21&linkId=87e0166e88287b253879972d859388eb&language=en_GB" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="//ws-eu.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=0134692888&Format=_SL160_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=GB&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=compucademy-21&language=en_GB" ></a><img src="https://ir-uk.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=compucademy-21&language=en_GB&l=li2&o=2&a=0134692888" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
```

The way the product building interface works, it looks like I need to extract the product link and the image sources for pasting in separate fields.

However there are two rather than one image sources and on inspection one of them is 1 px by 1 px.

Which of the image sources should I use as the URL for my product image? Obviously it makes sense to use bigger one, but are both needed for some reason?

Asking this question makes me wonder if there is some problem with dissecting the site stripe in this way...

Any insights please?

Answer (score 0):

The 1x1 image is a tracking pixel:

https://skillcrush.com/2012/07/19/tracking-pixel/

Comment: So I can ignore it? Is it otherwise OK to be using parts of the site stripe separately please?

Comment: I'm no expert at amazon affiliate program, but judging by what others say about it, I think it's OK as long as you use the stripe site:
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-use-Amazon-product-pictures-on-my-site
https://my.wealthyaffiliate.com/bryonbrewer/blog/using-amazon-product-images-on-your-site